# How do do "Facebook style" image tagging?

Tags: 7, media

I couldn't find a module that would allow "Facebook style" image tagging (select an area of an image and tag it with a username, for example).

Any good starting points to build such a feature?

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18290/image-annotations-in-drupal-7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called "image annotation" if you want to search for it.  There are a handful of modules, but not sure how great they work or how often they are maintained.  This one seemed the best:

http://drupal.org/project/image_annotate

Comment: Thank you. It seems D6 only but from there I found http://drupal.org/project/jq_maphilight which has a D7 dev version.