# Image Annotations in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, media

What's the best way of creating image annotations in Drupal 7?

Ideally, I would like to re-recreate something like in [Concept Feedback](http://www.conceptfeedback.com/concept-page/5850/web-site-redesign-for-simplicate-ca/), where you can post annotations on an image and then display the annotations as a list below the image, grouped by category.

[Image Annotate](http://drupal.org/project/image_annotate) ([view demo here](http://studioare.com/semipublic/annotate1/)), lets you annotate images. The annotations are also displayed as comments on the node (under the comments section). Unfortunately, it the Drupal 7 version is incomplete and not actively developed. The module also doesn't allow you much control over how comments are displayed and you can only annotate one image per a ndoe.

Photonotes ([view demo here](http://fotonotes-en.romka.eu/node/1/fotonotes)) is another similar module (although it only displays annotations on the image). It to is only in development for Drupal 6.

[JQMap Highlight](http://drupal.org/project/jq_maphilight) works on Drupal 7, only lets you post tooltips on images (as opposed to true annotations).

Does anyone have other suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Imagefield Marker](http://drupal.org/project/imagemarker) is a new D7 module for image annotations.

Comment: Thanks! This module doesn't let you display the annotations separately from the image. However, I bet it will possible to do that with some theming.

Comment: let me know if you figure out how to do that.

Comment: I've tried several times, but haven't got anything yet. To be honest, Imagefield Marker is a bit on basic side for my needs. It doesn't support multiple images, so you can only have one per a field. It also doesn't work with field collection[1] or Insert [2].
[1]http://drupal.org/project/field_collection
[2]http://drupal.org/project/insert

Comment: I played with it 2 days ago. Make sure to enable the "image marker" display for the image field. That's not documented on their homepage right now.

Answer (score 1):

If nobody knows a module like that, I think you could start porting Image Annotate to Drupal 7.

Comment: Thanks! But porting is beyond my current skill set.... :(

Comment: You can hire people at #drupal-consultants at Freenode, or at http://drupal.org/paid-services

Answer (score 0):

[Image Annotator](http://drupal.org/project/image_annotator) seems like a better option, tried Imagefield Marker too but had mixed results.