# Facebook like photo gallery with comments, tag photo, share etc

Tags: social-network, media

Is there any Facebook like photo gallery module with comments, tag photo, share option.
Please help in this.

Answer (score 4):

To annotate images in Drupal *7*: Imagefield Marker
http://drupal.org/project/imagemarker

See also: [Image Annotations in Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18290/image-annotations-in-drupal-7)

Very good multiple image uploader in Drupal 7:
Media module
http://drupal.org/project/media
(Quick way to get this is to create a free drupalgardens.com account and export the whole Drupal 7 code)

Comments are built-in in Drupal 7 for many content types.

Consider also:
http://drupal.org/project/disqus
(Drupal support for DISQUS a discussion comment system for integration with various social networking sites)

Also: Facebook Comments module:
http://beacon9.ca/labs/drupal-7-facebook-comments

I would suggest integrating comments with an existing social network as their authentication policies (particuarly Facebook's for example) can discourage trolls, spam and provide you with a centralised means of managing the comments, as well as spreading awareness of your site as their comments on your site are seen by their friends in their feeds).